# Excel: using vlookup but with wildcards in the array

Tags: arrays, excel, wildcard, vlookup

I have a list of values in a column on one sheet. On another sheet I have two columns. One is a list of wildcards, and the other is another list of values. Next to the column on the first sheet, I want an additional column to contain a formula that will check the value in the first column against the wildcards in the second sheet. If a match is found, it should display the value next to that wildcard.

Is there any way to do this? Been at it for hours and I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Some sample data:

**Sheet One**

Column A

randomunnecessarydataUSEFULTHINGS123INFOmoregarbage

morerandomstuffIMPORTANT456junkjunkjunk

IMPORTANT456lotsofmorejunk

morejunkUSEFULTHINGS789INFOgarbage

Column B

`<some formula>`

`<some formula>`

"

"

etc.

**Sheet Two**

Column A

`*usefulthings???INFO*`

`*important456*`

Column B

Useful Things - Info

Important 456

I want `<some formula>` to check the value in sheet 1 column A next to it against the table in Sheet 2. If one of the wildcard in sheet 2 column A match, the cell containing the formula should display what's in Sheet 2 column B.

Comment: Some data would help.  Please mock up some data and put it in the original post with the edit option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right you want something like this (in B1 and then copy down):

```
=IF(MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,A1,0)*ROW($1:$100),FALSE)),INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,A1,0)*ROW($1:$100),FALSE))),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]
Left is sheet 1 with the lookup term and right is sheet2 with the wildcard-list and the values.

**EDIT**
To auto-range it simply use this formula:

```
=IF(MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A)),A1,0)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A))),FALSE)),INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A)),A1,0)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A))),FALSE))),"")
```

And yes, only the first value will be outputted... if you want to get multiple values, you could use this formula (as always in B1 and then copy down and this time also to the left):

```
*² =IFERROR(IF(SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A)),$A1,0)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A))),FALSE),COLUMN()-1),INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A)),$A1,0)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A))),FALSE),COLUMN()-1)),""),"")
```

But keep in mind that all the formulas will slow down your excel the more cells use them (the last one the most). If your list is pretty long, I suggest a UDF.

**EDIT 2**

To speed it a bit up again you can use this formula for C1 (copy down / right) (just use the last formula only for column B):

```
=IF(B1="","",IFERROR(IF(SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A)),$A1,0)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A))),FALSE),COLUMN()-1),INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,SMALL(IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A)),$A1,0)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!$A:$A))),FALSE),COLUMN()-1)),""),""))
```

Also keep in mind that all formulas are array-formulas ;)

*² If using the first EDIT formula for column B and the EDIT 2 formula for column C+ you do not need the second EDIT formula.

**EDIT 3**

For the UDF-way go to your VBA-editor (hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and there "Insert" -> "Module". Then put in the code window for this module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getLikeLookup(str As String, rng As Range, Optional nCou As Long, Optional outCol As Range) As String

  'for not case sensitive
  str = LCase(str)

  'set ranges
  If nCou < 1 Then nCou = 1
  If outCol Is Nothing Then Set outCol = rng.Offset(, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Resize(, 1)
  Set rng = Intersect(rng.Resize(, 1), rng.Parent.UsedRange.EntireRow)
  Set outCol = Intersect(outCol.Resize(, 1), outCol.Parent.UsedRange.EntireRow)

  'get check-array (will be faster than running the sheet directly)
  Dim inArr As Variant
  inArr = rng.Value

  'run checks
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To UBound(inArr)
    'If str Like inArr(i, 1) Then nCou = nCou - 1
    If str Like LCase(inArr(i, 1)) Then nCou = nCou - 1 'for not case sensitive
    If nCou = 0 Then Exit For
  Next

  'check for valid output
  If i > UBound(inArr) Or i > outCol.Rows.Count Then Exit Function

  'set output
  getLikeLookup = outCol.Offset(i - 1).Resize(1, 1).Value

End Function
```

Now you are able to use your UDF like other worksheet functions. To explain this in detail.

```
getLikeLookup(lookup_string,lookup_range,[#_occurrence,[output_range]])
```

- `lookup_string`: the string you want to check against (the whole string, does not work with placeholder)
- `lookup_range`: the leftmost column in this range will be checked to be *like* `lookup_string`. If `output_range` is omitted then the rightmost column in `lookup_range` will be used for the output.
- `#_occurrence`: [optional] Indicates which match to output. If omitted (like 1) than the first one will be picked.
- `output_range`: [optional] the first column in `output_range` will be used for the output.

Now for the example you can use (starting in B1):

```
=getLikeLookup($A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,COLUMN()-1)
```

And to speed it up a bit use(still starting in B1):

```
=IF(A1="","",getLikeLookup($A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,COLUMN()-1))
```

This 2 formulas are no arrays and can be confirmed by just hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Let me go test this out. IN the meantime, any way to do this without the 100 row limit?

Comment: Also I'm guessing if a value matched more than one wildcard, it'd go with the first in the list?

Comment: I wouldn't totally be against using structured references here as well as the data in sheet 2 IS in a table with headers

Comment: so, if I'm understanding this correctly, the first formula in the edit should be able to match more than 100 entries in sheet 1 but would still be limited by 100 parameters in sheet 2 correct? (or am I not understanding the "ROW($1:$100)"s?)

I expect I'm going to have well over 500 (and possibly over 1000 rows in sheet 1. I'd guess this would slow down the file by quite a bit. Curious about the UDF option if that doesn't lag as much.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine in my test file. my only concern now is how much it might lag with a list of a few thousand items. You mentioned using a udf to handle this instead? how might I go about that?

Side note: what does the "zzz" do?

Comment: for the `A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))`: the part`MATCH("zzz",A:A)` will return the last row containing text (change "zzz" to 1E+99 to get the last numerical value) and knowing that `INDEX` can return a REF the `A1:INDEX(...)` can return a range and in this case having the last value in A1969 then `A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))` will return the ref to A1:A1969 (like you would directly enter it)... I'll add a UDF-way soon ;)

Comment: Wow that looks awesome. I'm eager to try it out! Would it work with structured references in the input/output ranges?

Comment: Should work with named ranges (also tables and whatever, as long as the return is a range and not an array). The `column()-1` is for getting the count. in column B it will be 2-1 (1) so the first match will be used for column b and in column C it will be 3-1 (2) so the second match will be used D = 3 / E = 4 etc. So if the first match would be in column D and the second in E etc then it would be `column()-3`. ;)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. This really helps a lot. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi, again. just a quick followup question to this, is there a way to escape * and ? if those characters are used in the first list? I tried excel's "~" but that doesnt'seem to work as it's being routed through a udf.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: In the wildcard searches, if I have a`*`a it will match to a<any_characters>a in sheet one, which is how it's supposed to work. but what if in sheet 1 there are entries that say "a`*`1","a`*`2","a`*`3", etc. and I want to find a*<one_character>. In sheet 2, `*` always translates to <any_characters> but I want to search for a`*`? where "`*`" is literal.

Comment: Simply put, how do I go about searching for `*` where `*` does not act as a wildcard character. same applies to "?"

Comment: If in sheet 2 it says `"a*a?"`, it will match to `"a*a<any 1 character>"` in sheet 1, but it will also match to "a123456789a<any 1 character>" and "aabcdefga<any 1 character>", etc.


In most cases this is the behavior you want as that is the point of a wildcard search, but in this instance, I want to be able to be able to specifically search for the strings that start with `"a*a"` and have <any 1 character> after it. So `a*a1`, `a*a2`, `a*a3`, etc. are all a match, but a!a1, or aba1, etc are not. In these cases I want to escape the `*` character so it does not act as a wildcard, but ? does

Comment: Does this clarify at all? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats

Comment: Unfortunately this is something complete different. As said: `str` does not work with wildcards. You would need to change the entries of the list to `a[*]a` to match it... pls check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)

Comment: I understood that the wildcard are in the range and the item to check against them are in the string? What I mean is that I want to search specifically for the character `"*"` in the string, but if I use that character in the range, it's interpreted as a wildcard

Comment: The default escape character in excel for such purposes is ~ though, not \. http://superuser.com/questions/458606/how-to-search-for-question-mark-in-excel

Comment: For the check we use the vba `Like` and not the search. Have you tried `a[*]a?`?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't sure how to interpret the character literally in VBA. non-case-sensitive works fine too. thanks for your help again!

Comment: Hopefully this won't take too much of your time but I have a bit of a weird add-on to this. Any way to prioritize the matches on Sheet 2 from the bottom up instead of top down? For example if the first entry was `*`, it wouldn't match it to that unless it didn't match anything else in the range. In other words - interpret the range upside-down

Comment: @creepblockedunderturret simply changing `For i = 1 To UBound(inArr)` to `For i = UBound(inArr) To 1 Step -1` should do it...